# Is there a way to embed an Angular web app inside a Spring Boot JAR file?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot web application that has JSPs for the web UI, REST APIs, and an embedded Tomcat server.  The customer gets a JAR file and runs it ... no other components required.

For the next version I'm building an Angular based web UI that uses the same REST APIs, and eliminates the JSP-based web GUI.

My question is ... does the Angular web app have to be run as a separate executable from the Spring Boot JAR file?   Is there a way to embed the Angular web app inside the Sprint Boot JAR file so the customer still only has to execute one JAR application?

Comment: I personally would keep them separate, and in separate git repositories as well. This simplfies builds, and maintainability, and you'll thank yourself down the line. Is there any particular reason you want to combine it?

Comment: As far as Spring is concerned, your Angular frontend is just static data (resources) that it can serve. There are advantages and disadvantages to serving through Spring instead of separately, but at that point it's just data.

Comment: @Blake The reason to combine them is the goal is to give the customer something that's easy to install and run.  Currently, the customer downloads the JAR file and runs it.  That's it.  If the web GUI is re-implemented with Angular loosing this simplicity of deployment would be a problem.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thanks, I'm new to Angular, working on tutorials. To run the app I'm doing `ng server --open` from cmd line ... not sure how I would run the Angular app as static files from Spring Boot app ... can you elaborate or point me in the right direction?